# print html entity in rails view using times method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to print Rating for bookmarks in rails view. I am trying to take out the **rating** ("3") from a hash and then convert that string to an int and then print solid star (html entity) that many times. Here is what I have been trying but it just prints the number. I am very new to ruby-on-rails, so I might be missing something very trivial here.

```
<% @bookmarks.each_with_index do |bookmark, index| %>
  <div class="bookmark">
    <%= link_to bookmark_path(index) do %>
        <ul>    
            <li><%= bookmark[:type] %></li>
            <li><%= bookmark[:title] %></li>
            <li>
              <%= bookmark[:rating].to_i.times do print "&bigstar;" end %>

              <%= bookmark[:rating].to_i.times do print "&bigstar;" end %>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out by myself.

```
<li>
      <% bookmark[:rating].to_i.times do %>
        &bigstar;
      <% end %>
</li>
```